# Create Powerpoint slides with R using template

Tags: r, templates, powerpoint

I need to do a powerpoint presentation and would like to use a given PPTX template for the formatting. Do you have any suggestions? Currently I am using knitr RMD files (ideally I could keep this).
Could you please also specify the packages you recommend?
Thanks!
Nils

Thanks for indicating the ReporteRs package. As I understand this package, I need to create each slide.

```
# I was looking for something like:
output:
  word_document:
    reference_docx: mystyles.docx
```

Comment: You want the package `ReporteRs` and from there `pptx(template = "mytemplate.pptx")`.

Answer (score 2):

The R package ReporteRs may be well suited to this task.  See:

http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/articles/powerpoint.html

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it explains only on how to extract parts of the document to a presentation slide. I am looking actually for a way to convert the whole document into a powerpoint. Similiar to:
    output:
      word_document:
        reference_docx: mystyles.docx

Comment: The document was moved to http://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/articles/powerpoint.html. I've suggested an edit.